# SonarQube skips analysis of ASP.NET Core project with views

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, sonarqube

When running a SonarQube analysis on a solution with multiple .NET Core 2.1 projects (libraries, unit tests, console, etc.), all projects are analyzed correctly by SonarQube, by invoking the following commands:

```
dotnet C:\SonarQube\sonar-scanner-msbuild-4.3.1.1372-netcoreapp2.0\SonarScanner.MSBuild.dll begin /k:"TST" 
dotnet build 
dotnet C:\SonarQube\sonar-scanner-msbuild-4.3.1.1372-netcoreapp2.0\SonarScanner.MSBuild.dll end
```

C# code in ASP.NET Core Web MVC projects is not analyzed however, the number of vulnerabilities and code smells are always zero, despite the fact all C# code is visible in SonarQube. Javascript code within the project is analyzed though. The SonarQube Scanner log does not contain any related warnings or errors.

This behaviour does not occur for ASP.NET Core Web API projects. The difference is that the latter doesn't have views. When I delete all the views in the MVC project, the code is analyzed correctly by SonarQube. Note that views (.cshtml files) are compiled in a separate DLL. The only reason I can think of is SonarQube (Community Edition 7.2.1) is confused by the DLL containing the views, or it can handle only handle a single project DLL.

Anyone any idea or maybe even a solution?